# BATCH - how to perform cyclic copy only for specific substring of folder name/file name?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder [C:\Users\name\desktop\New_Folder] with multiple folders and files. e.g.

```
New_Folder
    uuu_folder
    abcd_folder
    abcd_2_folder
    abcd_3_folder
    nnn.docx
    bbb.xlsx
```

I managed to "xcopy" all the files and folders in this folder to another folder. But, how can only "xcopy" the folders with only name started with abcd which only abcd_folder, abcd_2_folder and abcd_3_folder have copied?

```
set A_LOCAL=C:\Users\name\desktop\New_Folder
set B_LOCAL=C:\Users\name\desktop\Archive_Folder
set LIST=abcd
```

This is working for copying all the files and folders.

```
xcopy "%A_LOCAL%\*" "%B_LOCAL%\" /E
```

But this is not working for copying folders with specific subname of the folders?

```
xcopy "%A_LOCAL%\%LIST%_*" "%B_LOCAL%\" /E
```

Please help.

Comment: This is not possible with a single `xcopy` command; consider to use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead...

Comment: I tried with robocopy but somehow it popped out error with Invalid Parameter. It looked like it cannot recognize * to perform cyclic copy. Or, do you have success robocopy to share to the situation that i am going to perform?